# Paypal works in simulator but not in real device?

Tags: ios, paypal

I implement Paypal payment gateway in my app.
However, it works well in simulator but not in real device.
When I tap the Checkout with Paypal button, it hits this method

```
- (void)couldNotFetchDeviceReferenceToken
```

and logs this error in console:

```
FILE SYSTEM CHECK FAILED
Device interrogation failed.
```

What could be the cause?
I've tried to research it but they say need to use new Paypal API but I don't think it's the solution since it works well on simulator but not in real device.

Comment: I hope you aren't intending to submit this app to the App Store.  Apple won't accept an app that isn't using their IAP functionality.

Comment: Mine have been published in App Store. When I try to enhance it, it gives me such error, I never get the "File system check failed" before..

Comment: I stand corrected :) Looks like PayPal can be used for hard (non-digital) goods

Comment: yes, my app sells physical goods, not for in-app used..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was an error our on server side and is resolved now. Details were covered here on X.com: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/mobile/problems-paypal-api

Comment: I still get same error.."FILE SYSTEM CHECK FAILED
Device interrogation failed". Any advice?

Comment: hi Rendy - can you make sure you download the latest version of the library from x.com/mobile ? I just tried again and don't get into that error anymore.

Comment: hi Praveen, I downloaded the new library from here https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index#expresscheckoutnew but still has the same error :(

Comment: Can you tell me which device you are using? I wonder if there is anything specific about the make/model/version that our servers are not recognizing as a supported device.